# C++ Macro Not Working

Tags: c++, macros

The macro function I am defining doesn't seem to work.

> main.cpp:22:3: error: unknown type name 'a'
>     a *app = new a;
>    ^
>   main.cpp:22:16: error: unknown type name 'a'
>     a *app = new a;
>                  ^

Here is more source code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "monster.h"
#define DECLARE_MAIN(a)

class game : public monster::app {
  void init()
  {
  }
  void startup()
  {
  }
  void render(double currentTime)
  {
  }
};

DECLARE_MAIN(game)

int main(int argc, const char ** argv)
{
  a *app = new a;
  app->run(app);
  delete app;
  return 0;
}
```

If I were not to use the macro then no problems

```
int main(int argc, const char ** argv)
{
  game *app = new game;
  app->run(app);
  delete app;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I use this macro?

### Update

I think it was my lack of understanding how macros work and the source I was copying from.
I didn't realize the function following was part of the macro.

```
#define DECLARE_MAIN(a)                             \
int main(int argc, const char ** argv)              \
{                                                   \
    a *app = new a;                                 \
    app->run(app);                                  \
    delete app;                                     \
    return 0;                                       \
}
```

Comment: Well, I see no declaration of a type `a`, so listen to your compiler.

Comment: I don't know what you expect that macro to do, but it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Perhaps you'd find [preprocessing your source](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c98a2a4e2a78851) to be helpful.

Comment: What dou you actually think `#define DECLARE_MAIN(a)` should expand to?  There's no text for that macro defined at all.

Comment: we dont know what you are trying to do. YOu have defined a macro called DECLARE_MAIN that expands to nothing. YOu seem to expect this to change 'a' to 'game'

Comment: @Borgleader I considered not editing cause your comment was funny but I had to anyway. If you'd used the phrase ["derp combo"](www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Z2Z23SAFVA) I would have had to leave it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the sinking suspicion that you are trying to use a macro as a `typedef`.

It looks like what you meant to do was:

```
typedef game a;
```

Then you can do the line:

a* app = new a;

Answer (score 1):

Define your macro as:

```
#define DECLARE_MAIN(a) \
do {\
    a *app = new a; \
    app->run(app);\
    delete app;\
} while (0)
```

<s>Instead of writing `int main`, you simply write:</s>

Inside main, you do:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    DECLARE_MAIN(game);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This macro scares me.

Comment: Yup, any macro that encapsulates a function should very well scare anyone. But I think this is what OP was going for

Comment: @Smac89 No way you can be right. You could only call that macro once. Even if you did want to do this a `typedef` would be a far better solution.

Comment: @JonathanMee, ok I just recalled that the main function is the entry point of the entire program, so I propose a new solution, less scary, but still uses a macro

Comment: @Smac89 Better after edit, cause maybe it's reusable? But still impossible to debug. `typedef` is still by far a preferable solution.

Comment: @JonathanMee Can you explain what you mean by impossible to debug? I understand typedef is a better, but OP's question is `How can I use this macro?`

Comment: @Smac89 You're right here. **That's actually the correct way to define such kind of macro**. Avoiding any side effects by misplaced `;` semicolons, or scope contexts.

Comment: @Smac89 Copy that code into your IDE and try to put a breakpoint on say the `a *app = new a;` line.